# Unable to see iOS 17 devices in XCode 15

Tags: ios17, xcode15

I updated to XCOde 15 and iOS 17.
I am not able to see my iPad under Manage Run Destinations. ?

Is there any solution.

I am behind company firewall.

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance? Having the same issue with an iPad on iOS 17...

Comment: No. i am afraid its due to the firewall

Answer (score 3):

The cause should be VPN connection. Disconnect the VPN connection and try again.

Comment: Why would VPN cause iOS 17 devices to not be shown in Xcode and iOS 16 devices are fine? I disconnected from VPN and it still did not work.